# Как получать input когда запущен bot.infinity_polling()?

Tags: python, многопоточность, telebot

Мне надо получить input когда бот запущен, как это сделать?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.infinity_polling()
    while True:
        inp = input("enter something: ")
```

примерно так

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить проблему? Желательно с [с минимальным примером](/help/mcve) того, чего вы хотите получить.

Comment: В отдельном потоке попробуйте `inp = input("enter something: ")`. Потом запускайте до `bot.infinity_polling()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как предлагали в комментариях, нужно создать новый поток, в котором будет работать бот. Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
import threading

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=bot.infinity_polling, name='bot_infinity_polling', daemon=True).start()
    while True:
        inp = input("enter something: ")
```

Comment: Это не  работает

Comment: Я был почему то уверен полностью... Переделал под многопоточность, как предлагал @gil9red в комментариях.

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но это тоже не работает даже если в while я просто делаю print(1)

Comment: А сейчас, последнее решение в ответе, работает или нет?

Comment: Нужно пятнадцать символов. Нет

Comment: Я понятие не имею, почему у вас не работает. Такое же решение используется в [примерах библиотеки](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/f689d90815e8c20bc36853329c893f2801802bc9/examples/timer_bot.py#L38-L42).

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас пойду разбираться с примерами

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142856/discussion-between-mironovmeow-and-danya).